# Azure DevOps - Kanban board Filter menu Iteration does not list all the iterations

Tags: azure-devops

I create 3 iterations and assign features to these iterations.  So iteration1 has feature1.  iteration2 has feature2.  iteration3 has feature3.  In Kanban board with Feature view, I click on the Filter and click Iteration chevron menu.  But the menu shows the selections only for iteration1 and @currentIteration, but i hope to see iteration2 and iteration3 in the list too.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What options you can select in the filter menu depends on what Features are actually **visible** on the board.

For example, if only features belonging to iteration1 are visible, then only iteration1 (as well as current iteration will be visible for selection).

Thus you need to

1. Make sure you have assigned iteration2 and iteration3 to the team (under `project settins -> Team Configuration -> Iterations`)
2. Make sure that the features are visible on the board. If they are in the New or Done column they may be hidden, in that case you need to click the `Load More` link in the bottom of the column

Comment: Yep I understand about what filter is being selected in the Filter menu will show feature work items that match to that filter selection so I keep other filter selections (Types, Assigned To, Tags, Area, Parent Work Item) as default which means i don't check any checkbox except the Iteration filter where i click on it but it does not display iteration2 and iteration3 as one of the checkbox. ...[continue to next comment]

Comment: [continue from comment above]...  (1) yep, I assign iteration1, iteration2, and iteration3 in the Team Configuration-> Iteration.  (2) Iteration1 has Feature work items both as New and Active states, and they both show up under Iteration1 filter.  But for iteration2 and iteration3, they don't even show up in the Filter -> Iteration besides iteration1 and @currentIteration

Comment: Do Feature2 and Feature23 show up on the board if no filter are applied?

Comment: yes, if i don't filter, feature2 and feature3 show up after i click on blue text link that says Show more items.  after feature2 and feature3 show up, I click on feature2 and i see the Iteration field is assigned to iteration2 and feature3 has Iteration field assigned to iteration3

Comment: What if you filter **after** you click the blue text link that says "show more" (and Feature2 and Feature3 is visible), does that give you iteration2 and iteration3 as options in the iterations filter?

Comment: after talking to my internal team, your suggestion is correct.  After I finish loading all the work items in Backlog column in Kanban board, i need to check the Filter ->Iteration again then i see all the iterations.  thanks